# How to use 192.168.0.102 Virtual ip to connect remote mysql by cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, remote-server

this my php code

$con = mysqli_connect("212.1.212.1","******t","*****","bigcattl_formal") or die(mysql_error());

But have a problem . Access denied for mysql user 'bigcattl'

I can not connect mysql .
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that the user is infact a user is a viable/legit user in your MySQL database?

Comment: Have you provided required privileges to user bigcattl?

Comment: Yes  bigcattl is user in database.
Provided required privileges to user bigcattl?what is your mean?
Sorry not realize.

Comment: Thanks a lot my problem is solved.Cpanel ->adduser to database.